# Regex problems (preg_match)

Tags: php

I entered my flyer id as `abc` in input and stored it in `$flyerIDs`.

I want to validate that input does not contain anything except spaces, digits and comma and if it does throw error.

I have:

```
$error = preg_match("/[^\s,0-9]+/gi", $flyerIDs);
```

`$error` stores "". Don't understand why.

Comment: Error reporting & displaying or logging (either one of them or both), would have told you: **"PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g' "**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "g" is a valid modifier in PHP. Also, "i" would only be needed if matching letters.

```
$error = preg_match("/[^\s,0-9]+/", $ids);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know that the modifiers were specific to javascript .

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preg_match_all()` instead of `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: what can I use for i modifier?

Comment: @Aditya Nothing! `i` flag works as expected in PHP. But in your regex, actually you don't need it.

Comment: True.that makes sense! thnx